# Why store python keywords in a mutable object?

Tags: python-2.7

The python module `keyword` stores all the python keywords in a list

```
>> import keyword
>> keyword.kwlist
```

output

```
['and',
 'as',
 'assert',
 'break',
 'class',
 'continue',
 'def',
 'del',
 'elif',
 'else',
 'except',
 'exec',
 'finally',
 'for',
 'from',
 'global',
 'if',
 'import',
 'in',
 'is',
 'lambda',
 'not',
 'or',
 'pass',
 'print',
 'raise',
 'return',
 'try',
 'while',
 'with',
 'yield']
```

since `list` is a mutable object and i can modify add above list and some random stuff

```
kwlist.append("notakeyword")
```

then "notakeyword" will be part of python keyword list, which should not.

Immutable data structure can be used instead of mutable.

Is any rational behind using mutable object (list) and not using immitable (like tuple) ?

Comment: would it really matter though? to the best of my knowledge it doesnt modify the interpreter

Comment: @DTSCode it doesn't; if you add to `kwlist`, that won't mean `SyntaxError` if you assign to your new "keyword". It's just for information.

Comment: There's nothing special in your example. You can break things in the standard library in all sorts of ways: reassign bad values to module-level variables, delete attributes from instances of standard classes (if they have a `__dict__`), etc. We are all grownups here.

Comment: jonrsharpe yeah thats what i thougt... although it is curious why they didnt do tuple. i might push that change if there is no downside

Comment: @shx2, its not about breaking the system...  just curious why they used list instead of other suitable data structure.